# Swagger UI missing post configuring in WEBAPI

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have installed Swashbuckle to configure Swagger for my webapi. But while browsing I am unable to view swagger UI.

error :

[image: Click here to view error]

How to enable swagger UI in webapi.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the setting in Startup.cs file like below

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
                {
                    Version = "v1",
                    Title = "some title",
                    Description = "Web API",
                    TermsOfService = "None",
                    Contact = new Contact()
                    {
                        Name = "some name",
                        Email = "someemail@xxxx.com",
                        Url = "<url>"

                    }
                });

                c.OperationFilter<FileUploadOperation>();

            });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "my api 12345");
            });
}
```

Comment: In new webapi project, I just installed  Package Swashbuckle and while browsing Swagger UI displayed. But in my existing old webapi, UI was empty after installing swagger package.

Comment: Did u configured the same settings for old web api ? please post some code so it will be helpful to provide the solution.